# Problem with loading a json file for geo_data in python

Tags: python, json, geojson, folium, choropleth

I am currently trying to use folium library in python to create webmaps. I have a file `world.json` which contains geo_data. I have provided a link to the file at the end of this post. I tried the following code:

```js
data = [json.loads(line) for line in open('world.json', 'r')]
```

and received the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

How can I load this file?

What I want to achieve is essentially obtain the population data and create a Choropleth and overlay it on my webmap.

Edit: Forgot the link:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Army95vqcKXpaooVAZU_g-VCAVw?e=vwTknq

Edit: Previous link to skydrive stopped working due to "high traffic". Below is link to dropbox, hopefully this works:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gmm8db0g03rc7cv/world.json?dl=0

Comment: I cannot see the link to the file, can you put it in the post?

Comment: @Aramakus I am sorry, I thought I edited it yesterday, but I guess it didn't go through. The following is the link: 1drv.ms/u/s!Army95vqcKXpaooVAZU_g-VCAVw?e=vwTknq

Comment: No worries @Zarak ! Maybe that's just me, but I cannot access your oneDrive link, it says `This item might not exist or is no longer available`.

Comment: Please, provide the json file, otherwise your question will be closed. Thanks.

Comment: @Aramakus I uploaded the file to skydrive and then it was working initially, but stopped working because of high traffic apparently. I have uploaded it to dropbox now, hopefully it works:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gmm8db0g03rc7cv/world.json?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news/bad news:
It turns out that this file was encoded in a locale that we are not accustomed to, and json/ascii cannot make sense of some of the character encoding.  I tried this, and it seems to be working for me -- with a major caveat:

```
with open("world.json", "r") as fh:
    contents = fh.read()
asciiContents = contents.encode("ascii", errors="ignore")
data = json.loads(asciiContents)
```

The major caveat is that only 3 countries come through with no encoding errors:

```
>>> len(data["features"])
3
```

Maybe there another source for this data that is closer to a native english locale, or maybe someone else can provide wisdom in encoding foreign data in a more friendly way...

Comment: Thanks a lot, it actually worked for me. 

>>> len(data["features"])      returns 246 for me. I am able to access the data I wanted to access.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

The open command will return a file handle, not string lines. I would do:

```
with open('world.json', 'r') as fh:
    data = json.load(fh)
```

data will then be your contents converted to python (list or dictionary, etc)

Comment: Hello astetson, thank you for your response!

However, I receive the same error again. I have edited the post to include link to the file.

Comment: Ahah, okay so it looks like this file was written with non-ascii encoding. If this is read into `vim`, you'll see this message at the bottom:
`".\world.json" [noeol][converted] 1L, 7715C`

Similarly, if you read the contents into python and try to encode it as ascii:

`>>> contents = contents.encode("ascii")`
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)`

I'll have to search around to see how to resolve this.